# Multithreaded Monte Carlo pi calculation loses precision with more threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, random, pthreads

I am writing a simple benchmarking application to assess/compare multithreading performance of pthreads and OpenMP. To do so I use the Monte Carlo Method to calculate Pi, distributing the iterations over a number of threads.

I wrote a small and simple wrapper Class around the pthreads interface that just creates a thread when an object is constructed and stores the thread id.

Now for my problem: I have found that if I spawn more than one thread it seems that the for-loop inside of this thread does not get executed. I have tested this by incrementing a variable inside of the loop which remains zero for all, but the last thread. Weirdly enough that doesn't happen on every run of the program.
Adding a delay between the creation of threads remedies the problem, but I really don't understand why.

```
void* monteCarlo_intern(void* args){
    struct thread_arguments* arguments = (struct thread_arguments*) args;

    long unsigned int total=0;
    long unsigned int inside=0;

        thread_local std::mt19937_64 generator(std::random_device{}());
    thread_local std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0, 1.0);

    double d1 = 0, d2 = 0;
    for(total = 0; total < arguments -> iterations; total++) {
                d1 = distribution(generator);
                d2 = distribution(generator);

        if((d1*d1 + d2*d2) <= 1.0) {inside++;}
    }
    *arguments->inside = inside * 4;
}

double calcPI_monteCarlo(struct for_arguments args_in){

  std::vector <long unsigned int> inside_vec(args_in.no_threads - 1, 0);  //Vector to hold results per thread
  std::vector<Thread> threads;  //Vector to hold threads
  const unsigned long int iters_per_t = args_in.iterations / args_in.no_threads;

  std::vector<thread_arguments> args(args_in.no_threads - 1, {NULL, iters_per_t});

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < args_in.no_threads - 1; i++)
  {
    args[i].inside = &inside_vec[i];                        //Assign results-vector adress to thread to capture result
    threads.emplace_back(monteCarlo_intern, &args[i]);      //Create thread and store it in vector
  }

  long unsigned int inside = 0;
  thread_arguments local_args = {&inside, iters_per_t};
  monteCarlo_intern(&local_args);    //Do the same calculation locally to reduce number of spawned threads

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < args_in.no_threads - 1; i++)
  {
    pthread_join(threads[i].get_id(), NULL);
    inside += inside_vec[i];
  }

  long unsigned int total = iters_per_t * args_in.no_threads;
  return (double)inside / total;
}
```

Comment: @Eljay `thread_local` is implicit `static`. I would make distribution thead_local as well, but it should work as it is

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux • Thanks!  I did not know that.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Max, Max, Max, we're talking about initialization and life time.  C++17 standard, 6.6.4.2 `All variables declared with the thread_local keyword have thread storage duration. The storage for these
entities shall last for the duration of the thread in which they are created.` So it is implicit `static` for a (given) thread.

Comment: @Eljay More precisely, it is like `static` but for a thread. C++17, 6.6.4.2 `All variables declared with the thread_local keyword have thread storage duration. The storage for these
entities shall last for the duration of the thread in which they are created.`

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Word `static` is missing in your quotes.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Sure, let's continue with 6.6.4.3 `Block-scope variables not explicitly declared static, thread_local, or extern have automatic storage
duration. The storage for these entities lasts until the block in which they are created exits.` Does it make you happy?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I see what you mean now. However, `static` makes linkage internal, whereas `thread_local` doesn't.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin  In block scope, `thread_local` and `thread_local static` mean exactly the same thing. The lifetime is that of the thread and linkage is internal.

Comment: @doug If they were the same thing `thread_local` would not be needed. They do have the same linkage at block scope though, so that `static` would be superfluous there and I stand corrected in this regard.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin  Agreed.  Only *In block scope* do `thread_local` and `thread_local static` mean the same thing.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I hope doug cleared everything wrt `thread_local` - in the context of the OP code `thread_local` is implicit `static`. Personally, I would prefer it to be called `thread_static`, but we have what we have.

Comment: It is hard to see where the problem is without seeing your pthread wrapper class. F.e., where is pthread_create() called? On constructor call in `emplace_back()`? If you're usinf C++11, I would consider coding for standard threads